# Ubuntu terminal colors TOO boring

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Lets say I run rails tests

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSUyC.png

Is whta I get. Which is ugly. = (

I want something with more colors. Is there anything that I can code to make the terminal more colorful or are there better terminals out there with respect to color. I thought of trying X-Term but I'll ask here first!

Thank you

Comment: Can't you configure the colors manually? Btw. try askUbuntu

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines. It is better suited for [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [su].

Comment: Ahh sorry Ken! I'll take it down

Comment: Shomz, I tried! However it barely affects colors outside of VIM. = C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash itself isn't much colorable. You could get a custom prompt ([examples](http://jamiedubs.com/ps1-collection-customize-your-bash-prompt)) or a custom color scheme for gtk itself.

Another option is switching to different Shell. Check out oh-my-zsh on GitHub. Easy installation, powerful completion, and LOADS of themes.

Comment: zsh themes viewer: http://zshthem.es/all/

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of options available. Do a web search to find ones that you like. Personally, I use this [one](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/).